# Weird error in listing values from object

Tags: apex, visualforce, custom-field, sobjecttype

Good afternoon, I'm currently having a problem which I don't know absolutely why it is happening. The following is an example:

"The value '9/18/2013' is not a valid number
Error is in expression '`{!var.Field__c}`' in component `<apex:column>` in component blabla"

Any idea as to why this is occurring? I have another field which I can list and is exactly the same, Type Text and same length, only on this one in particular I'm having problems.

Best regards

**EDIT:**

```
<apex:pageBlockTable value="{!param}" var="var">
     <apex:column value="{!var.id}"/>
     <apex:column value="{!var.Field__c}"/>
     <apex:column value="{!var.Field2__c}"/>
     <apex:column value="{!var.Field3__c}"/>
</apex:pageBlockTable>
```

Every field works except the apex:column value="{!var.Field__c}"/>

Note: The value 9/18/2013 has already been inserted, but you probably knew that already since it shows the value in question.

Comment: Can you edit your question and show us the difference between the VF `apex:column` markup of the field which does work and the field which does not work?

Comment: Post some code please.

Comment: Sorry about that, have now edited the post.

Comment: So Field__c, Field2__c, and Field3__c all have the same data type? Are they all Dates?

Comment: No, these are all Text Type except id

Comment: The problem is occurring elsewhere; either in the rest of the Visualforce page, the Apex controller, or maybe a validation rule. Does this happen when the page loads, or as part of an action?

Comment: It happens when the page loads... Field__c is basically a copy of Field2__c and Field3__c, same way of presenting it but somehow I just can't display its value because of the error shown above.

Comment: What happens if you use `<apex:outputField>` wrapped in `<apex:column>` tags instead?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried changing the structure of your columns and not putting the column value directly in the tag:

```
<apex:pageBlockTable value="{!param}" var="var">
    <apex:column>
        <apex:facet name="header">Id</apex:facet>
        <apex:outputField value="{!var.Id}" />
    </apex:column>
    <apex:column>
        <apex:facet name="header">Field</apex:facet>
        <apex:outputField value="{!var.Field__c}" />
    </apex:column>
    <apex:column>
        <apex:facet name="header">Field 2</apex:facet>
        <apex:outputField value="{!var.Field2__c}" />
    </apex:column>
    <apex:column>
        <apex:facet name="header">Field 3</apex:facet>
        <apex:outputField value="{!var.Field3__c}" />
    </apex:column>
<apex:pageBlockTable>
```

maybe you would get the value in your field that you were looking for and you should not need to worry for formatting the output for dates like you have in your output. Otherwise, if you know that you have dates for these field types you could possibly just use outputText instead of outputField and format it like below:

```
<apex:pageBlockTable value="{!param}" var="var">
    <apex:column>
        <apex:facet name="header">Id</apex:facet>
        <apex:outputField value="{!var.Id}" />
    </apex:column>
    <apex:column>
        <apex:facet name="header">Field</apex:facet>
        <apex:outputText value="{0, DATE, MM"/"dd"/"yyyy}">
            <apex:param value="{!var.Field__c}" />
        </apex:outputText>
    </apex:column>
    <apex:column>
        <apex:facet name="header">Field 2</apex:facet>
        <apex:outputText value="{0, DATE, MM"/"dd"/"yyyy}">
            <apex:param value="{!var.Field2__c}" />
        </apex:outputText>
    </apex:column>
    <apex:column>
        <apex:facet name="header">Field 3</apex:facet>
        <apex:outputText value="{0, DATE, MM"/"dd"/"yyyy}">
            <apex:param value="{!var.Field3__c}" />
        </apex:outputText>
    </apex:column>
<apex:pageBlockTable>
```

Comment: This question is from 2013. Although it is kind of you to provide an answer, I doubt the OP is still looking for one ;)

Comment: Haha, yeah I realized it after the post- however if it will help another down the road

Comment: Yeah, I've been there too :D